# Convert spline interpolation to linear interpolation?

Tags: r

This function below is doing good job for spline interpolation but I wonder how can I modify it to do linear interpolation instead!

```
  ## Function to interpolate using spline
    imageSpline = function(x, y, xout, method = "natural", ...){
    x.max = max(xout)
    x.spline = spline(x = x, y = y, xout = xout, method = method, ...)
    x.spline
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?approx` for `approx()` and `approxFun()`. These are the linear interpolation counterparts to `spline()` and `splineFun()`.

Depending on the detail of the linear interpolation you want to perform (see `?approx` for the details and things to tweak), it could be as simple as:

```
imageApprox <- function(x, y, xout, ...) {
    x.linear <- approx(x = x, y = y, xout = xout, ...)
    x.linear
}
```

Comment: @temor No, sorry; copy-paste error that I have now fixed. Sorry about that... (I was being lazy)

Comment: Not that I can see; `approx` works in the similar way as to `spline`, returning `$x` and `$y components. This should be a plugin replacement for your code using `spline()`.