# Interpolation on info of raster

Tags: r, interpolation

I have 6 `.tif` files. Every file represent the same area, just for different year : `1990`, `1995`, `2000`, `2005`, `2010`, `2015`.

So they all have the same coordinates.

I manage to extract `x`, `y`, and the value corresponding of the couple `x,y` so no problem with that.

Now i have 6 `data.frames`, each contain x,y and the value, for `1990`, `1995`, `2000`, `2005`, `2010`, `2015`.

What i want to do is, use the interpolation to find the value for each cell, for the other years (`1991`, `1992`, ..., `2014`).

NB:If you want to see my code let me know, but i didn't write a thing for my problem, i can't see how to "attack" it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpolate between rasters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127122/how-to-interpolate-between-rasters)

Comment: Mhm that's not me, i looked the topic, i thought with a bit of lucky it would be the same problem and data structur, but no ...

Comment: This is the exact same problem. Please read correctly the existing answers:
`s <- stack(r1990, r1995,..., r2015)
x <- calc(s, fun=function(y) approx(seq(1,26,5), y, 1:26)$y)`

Comment: Alright, entirely my bad. I adapt the code, but i have an error : "Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list' ", do you know what can i do to fix it ? I'm looking for solution, but i don't know why it does that. I'm working with dataframe so it should be good

Comment: The stack doesn't work, so i tried to create a vector with my dataframe, but nothing seems to work

Comment: [`stack`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/stack) takes `raster` of the same extent as input, not `dataframe`.